# After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, wine stopped working. After reinstalling it, I get dependency issues

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

I have upgraded my Ubuntu version from 16.04 to 18.04. After that wine programs stopped working. I have re-installed wine and now I'm getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 wine64 : Depends: libwine (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I can't even install FileZilla from software center.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do you get after `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Looks like sometime in the past you installed (or upgraded) wine (or playonlinux or some other wine derivative) from some non-Ubuntu source. If so, the packages provided by that non-Ubuntu source are still installed - find those packages and remove them.